# order records with a search

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I have order records to be able to work with it?

I tried

```
not_clean_data = self.env['my_model'].search([],order = 'user_id, datetime asc')
```

but in vain

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to provide order rule for each field separately:

```
not_clean_data = self.env['my_model'].search([], order='user_id desc, datetime asc')
```

Comment: I tried it but always it returns the records as they r on my_model

Answer (score 0):

Define in your py  file

```
 def _get_default_data(self):
                        not_clean_data = self.env['my_model'].search([], order='user_id desc, datetime asc, limit=1)
                        print "group:"
                        return not_clean_data

        xyz = fields.Many2one('my_model', "ABC", change_default=True, default=_get_default_data)
```

I hope it helps you.
Thanks